# Как работать c wchar_t?

Tags: c++

Простой пример работы с широкой строкой: подсчет кликов мыши.
Как сделать код лучше?

```
// глобальная константа
wchar_t pMsg[30] = L"Приветствие";
// что можно использовать вместо статического массива?
// избежать переполнения, отсутствия нуль символа
int counter = 0;// счетчик нажатий

// процедура (функция) вывода сообщения (обработки данных)
int MyFunction() {
    wcscpy_s(pMsg, 15, L"Всего кликов ");
    wchar_t buffer[3];
    swprintf_s(buffer, 3, L"%d ", ++counter);
    wcscpy_s(pMsg, wcslen(pMsg) + wcslen(buffer) + 1, buffer);
    return 0;
}

// ...

//внутри обработчика событий
case WM_PAINT:
{
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    TextOut(hdc, 5, 5, pMsg, wcslen(pMsg));
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    MyFunction(void); // возможно принимает параметры
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    break;
}
```

Comment: я вижу строчку кода. В чем вопрос?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235631.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Ну, я бы в любом случае не стал копировать что-то в строку-литерал - она по определению константна, ее компилятор имеет право вообще разместить в r/o-памяти.